# ServiceWorkers: what's the difference between importScripts and self.importScripts

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I manage multiple sites that use third party services for sending push notifications. There are two different services used by different sites in our network. The services require registering a service worker and they each supply the code for the service worker.

One has

```
importScripts('https://xyz-push-provider.com/somewhere/file.js');
```

and the other has

```
self.importScripts('https://abc-push-provider.co/foo/bar/different-file.js');
```

That's it for each of them. There's no scoping or functions or anything.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self):

> The self read-only property of the WorkerGlobalScope interface returns a reference to the WorkerGlobalScope itself

So then why is `self` necessary at all? Are these two lines any different or can I just remove `self.` from the second one?

Comment: "*So then why is `self` necessary at all?*" - well as you can see, it's not.

Comment: Actually @Bergi I can't see, that's why I posted this. I have edited the post to indicate the 2 URLs loaded are different and emphasise there are two different third party services. For all I know the js inside them addresses different scopes, or whatever. I was hoping someone could just explain in simple terms what `self` means in this context.

Comment: Ah I thought you had kinda the same script and saw it working both with and without `self`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.` is only needed when there is a preferred `scope` value such as this:

```js
function main() {
  function importScripts(url: string) {
    console.log('import scripts custom')
  }

  // right now if you call `importScripts` only the above function will be called. you must call `self.importScripts`
```

in general `self.` allows for more semantic clarity